# Move of time machine backup: unable to "restore"

Tags: time-machine, restore, disk-utility

I want to use a new hard drive for time machine. I try to restore the old backup into the new disk using disk utility. It fails with the following error :

> source volume is read-write and cannot be unmounted, so it can't be
>   block copied

Why ?
What can I do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem understood. The disks were actually locked by the failed copy of the backup folder I tried to do between the two disks shortly before.

If it happens to you, just make sure the disks are not locked. In the worse case, reboot.

Comment: Please mark this as the answer if your issue is resolved. Thank you!

Comment: any chance you could elaborate on this? Ive no idea what any of this means, but reboot didn't help